# Check if file exists, if not then display specific div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using onclick show function to accomplish following sequence..

1. Onclick, a div with content will appear for 5 seconds
2. After 5 secs, old div hides and new div with content appears

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
    setTimeout("hide()", 5000);  // 5 seconds
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
    show2();
}

function show2() {
    document.getElementById("Div2").style.display="block";
}
```

I want to add one more step here...

3. Onclick, check if a text file exists on a website and at the same time display a div for 5 secs
4. Display specific div if file **does not** exists
5. Display another div if file **exists**

Comment: Is the "text file" accessible through a URL, or else is there an API endpoint on the server that will report on the existence of the text file?

Comment: the txt file is accessible via url @PeterB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Peter said correct. CORS will prevent you accomplishing what you want. This can be done easily if you want to do this on your own down.

You will need to add one more div and a function.

```js
var url1 = "https://YourDomain.com/Exists.txt";


 HideAll();

 function HideAll() {
 $("#divExists").hide();
 $("#divNotExists").hide();
 }

 function Check(url) {
 HideAll();
 $.get(url,
 function(response, status, jqXhr) {
  $("#divExists").show().html("<b>OK");
  show1();
 }

 )
 .fail(function(response, status, jqXhr) {
  $("#divNotExists").show().html("<b>Not found");
 }
 );
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="Check(url1)">Check URL 1</button>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function show1() {
  document.getElementById("myDivv").style.display="block";

  }

  function show() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
  setTimeout("hide()", 5000);  // 5 seconds
  }

  function hide() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
  show2();
  }

  function show2() {
  document.getElementById("Div2").style.display="block";
  }
  </script>
```

and then....

```
  <button onclick="Check(url1)">Check URL 1</button>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function show1() {
  document.getElementById("myDivv").style.display="block";

  }

  function show() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
  setTimeout("hide()", 5000);  // 5 seconds
  }

  function hide() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
  show2();
  }

  function show2() {
  document.getElementById("Div2").style.display="block";
  }
  </script>

  <div id = "myDivv" style="display:none"><input type = "button" value = "Proceed" onclick = "show()"><br>clicking above will launch 5 sec div</div>



   <div id = "myDiv" style="display:none">This is show()</div><br>
   <div id="Div2" style="display:none">This is show2()</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if a file exists or not can be done using the **`success`** and **`fail`** callbacks of the jQuery [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method, see the snippet below.

**Note** that in the snippet, no URL will **ever** load anything because (a) the URLs are invalid, and (b) *even with valid URLs*, the configured [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policies of the domain `stacksnippets.com` make any kind of Ajax requests impossible to succeed. Meaning that when you run it, you will only see the `fail` scenario happen.

CORS may also be an important factor to consider for your own domain.

Also note that you will have to put your `show/hide a certain DIV` logic inside the `success` and `fail` callback functions, or at least you'll need to call the relevant code from there.

```js
var url1 = "https://YourDomain.com/Exists.txt";
var url2 = "https://YourDomain.com/DoesNotExist.txt";

HideAll();

function HideAll() {
  $("#divExists").hide();
  $("#divNotExists").hide();
}

function Check(url) {
  HideAll();
  $.get(url,
    function(response, status, jqXhr) {
      $("#divExists").show().html("<b>" + url + "</b> OK");
    }
   )
   .fail(function(response, status, jqXhr) {
      $("#divNotExists").show().html("<b>" + url + "</b> Not found");
    }
   );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="Check(url1)">Check URL 1</button>
<button onclick="Check(url2)">Check URL 2</button>

<div id="divExists"></div>
<div id="divNotExists"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way to check existence of a file in local drive FROM a local file using javascript? Meaning the file will be run from the same pc and it should check whether a file is present or not on mentioned location.